'By', 'according to' or 'following' when speaking of following regulations, protocols, etc
I have a blank spot regarding the use of the preposition by in the meaning of according to and following. Since by is the shortest option of the three, I would be happy to use it in place of according to or following whenever possible for the sake of concision.
Hereby, I'll make up a few example sentences to illustrate my case of confusion.


The stadium was evacuated by/according to/following the set protocol.
The search party was acting by/according to/following the orders.
The accounting reports were conducted by/according to/following the official standards.


I would be specifically happy to know if there are cases of this ilk whereby the use of the preposition by will be categorically incorrect.

Expressions like  by order and by law are well-established, but I find by a bit awkward in your examples. (The set protocol didn't evacuate the stadium.)

A friendly tip: Open-ended questions (questions like, *What are some examples of…?”) are frowned upon here. The standard is to post your question in a form that elicits a single explicit answer.

by is unnatural or incorrect in all of your examples. You could use the idiom by the rules to end your sentences (e.g. The search party was acting by the rules) — but that’s about it.

Note that for by, the meaning according to is recorded in dictionaries after the meaning of agency:

preposition (AGENT)
used to show the person or thing that does something:

The motorcycle was driven by a tiny bald man. (Cambridge)


If these two meanings are not clearly distinguished and there is ambiguity as to whether it is used with one meaning or the other, by should be avoided.
Thus, your example

The stadium was evacuated by the set protocol.

is ambiguous (and by will be ambiguous after passive verbs), as it could be misunderstood as meaning that the set protocol is the agent of the evacuation. You are fine using according to here, no need to avoid it just because it is comprised of two words. Unambiguity is king.
The same issue for your third example. As for your second example, it strikes me as not natural, even if by would be unambiguous here. According to or following would be more indicated.
With the meaning you are looking for, by is commonly used in expressions as play by the rules, abide by [the law], by one's standards, etc.
